# How can I configure my repository and TravisCI to automate deployments to GAE standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, travis-ci

I'm in the process of configuring my Go app to be able to be automatically deployed on pushes to `master` on GitHub.

So far, I've been able to set it up using Google App Engine's flexible environment but I'm unable to take advantage of the free tier by doing so. I'm pretty sure what I'm doing wrong is misconfiguring my `cloudbuild.yml` file since it *seems* like the code is actually getting to GAE but it will not run when it gets there.

Here's my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go112
```

Here's my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  - name: 'golang'
    args: ['go', 'build', '.']
    env: ['GO111MODULE=on']
```

The Go app itself is relatively standard in its layout/design and can be found [here where I'm working on the "gae-standard" branch](https://github.com/forstmeier/watchmyrepo/tree/gae-standard).

I'd ideally love to have:
- TravisCI run tests/deploy code to GAE
- GAE running the code in the standard environment

If anyone has a good example to point me at, or some insight into what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You have it configured to build your app but is there anything telling GAE how to run it?

Comment: Doesn't push to GAE, but github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas has some good Cloud Build + GCR stuff to look at.

Comment: @user2896976 No, and I think that's my gap in understanding. Where/how would that be invoked?

Comment: @sethvargo Seems like a good resource and you're right, I can't see anything related to GAE pushes.

Comment: These docs should lead you in the right direction. In the Deploying Artifacts section select "App Engine". https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts

Comment: @Jesse I've tried a couple different variations of what I found in that resource but I'm not able to get it to work. I assume I would keep my `.travis.yml` file as is: https://github.com/forstmeier/watchmyrepo/blob/gae-standard/.travis.yml. I'm still not seeing artifacts/files appearing in GAE either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have 2 main questions here.

1- How automatically deployed on pushes to master on GitHub?
   For this you can use Running builds on GitHub[1].
   Google Cloud Build lets you create fast, consistent, reliable builds across all 
   languages. Automatically build containers or non-container artifacts on commits to 
   your GitHub repository. Get complete control over defining custom workflows for 
   building, testing, and deploying across multiple environments such as VMs, 
   serverless, Kubernetes, or Firebase.

2.-How to set-up Google App Engine's flexible environment to take advantage of the free tier?
  From my point of view you where well addressed by @Jesse

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github

Comment: The first point yes, I could try configuring that option as well. I tried it previously but it didn't yield any real results and I was basically where I am now. Regarding the second point, if you look at the [Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) section, it seems to indicate that only standard environment is free whereas flexible is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `watchmyrepo.db` file was exactly the problem or at least that's what it looks like in the logs (which I failed to find/review). I'm planning on migrating this over two Datastore or something else and moving off of BoltDB so that should alleviate the issue.

It was all just coding issues on my part that were generating 500/502 errors and those have now all been resolved - thanks!